# Move item form one List<> to another. C#

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am new to programming and very new to c#, I'm trying to to create a black jack game for a course I'm taking and am having trouble early on.

What I am trying to do is move an item from one List<> to another. Or if its easier; add the item to the other list first the just delete the item from the original List<>.(or if I'm going about this totally wrong any advise would be great thanks)

So move a card from the deck: cards to another list: `playerHand`.

This is the List<> "Deck of Cards"

```
public Deck()
{
    //add card suits- 
    cards = new List<Cards>();
    // Hearts
    cards.Add(new Cards("Ace", "Hearts", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("2", "Hearts", 2));
    cards.Add(new Cards("3", "Hearts", 3));
    cards.Add(new Cards("4", "Hearts", 4));
    cards.Add(new Cards("5", "Hearts", 5));
    cards.Add(new Cards("6", "Hearts", 6));
    cards.Add(new Cards("7", "Hearts", 7));
    cards.Add(new Cards("8", "Hearts", 8));
    cards.Add(new Cards("9", "Hearts", 9));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Jack", "Hearts", 10));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Queen", "Hearts", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("King", "Hearts", 12));
    // Diamonds
    cards.Add(new Cards("Ace", "Diamonds", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("2", "Diamonds", 2));
    cards.Add(new Cards("3", "Diamonds", 3));
    cards.Add(new Cards("4", "Diamonds", 4));
    cards.Add(new Cards("5", "Diamonds", 5));
    cards.Add(new Cards("6", "Diamonds", 6));
    cards.Add(new Cards("7", "Diamonds", 7));
    cards.Add(new Cards("8", "Diamonds", 8));
    cards.Add(new Cards("9", "Diamonds", 9));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Jack", "Diamonds", 10));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Queen", "Diamonds", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("King", "DIamonds", 12));
    // Spade
    cards.Add(new Cards("Ace", "Spades", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("2", "Spades", 2));
    cards.Add(new Cards("3", "Spades", 3));
    cards.Add(new Cards("4", "Spades", 4));
    cards.Add(new Cards("5", "Spades", 5));
    cards.Add(new Cards("6", "Spades", 6));
    cards.Add(new Cards("7", "Spades", 7));
    cards.Add(new Cards("8", "Spades", 8));
    cards.Add(new Cards("9", "Spades", 9));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Jack", "Spades", 10));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Queen", "Spades", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("King", "Spades", 12));
    // Clubs
    cards.Add(new Cards("Ace", "Clubs", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("2", "Clubs", 2));
    cards.Add(new Cards("3", "Clubs", 3));
    cards.Add(new Cards("4", "Clubs", 4));
    cards.Add(new Cards("5", "Clubs", 5));
    cards.Add(new Cards("6", "Clubs", 6));
    cards.Add(new Cards("7", "Clubs", 7));
    cards.Add(new Cards("8", "Clubs", 8));
    cards.Add(new Cards("9", "Clubs", 9));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Jack", "Clubs", 10));
    cards.Add(new Cards("Queen", "Clubs", 11));
    cards.Add(new Cards("King", "Clubs", 12));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Card cardToMove = cards[0];
cards.Remove(card);
playerHand.Add(card);
```

---

And maybe a cleaner way to create all the card deck:

```
List<string> types = new List<string> { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };
List<dynamic> cards = new List<dynamic>
{
    new {Text = "Ace", Number = 11 },
    new {Text = "2", Number = 2},
    new {Text = "3", Number = 3},
    new {Text = "4", Number = 4},
    new {Text = "5", Number = 5},
    new {Text = "6", Number = 6},
    new {Text = "7", Number = 7},
    new {Text = "8", Number = 8},
    new {Text = "9", Number = 9},
    new {Text = "Jack", Number = 10 },
    new {Text = "Queen", Number = 11 },
    new {Text = "King", Number = 12 }
};

var cardDeck = (from type in types
                from card in cards
                select new Card(card.Text, type, card.Number)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i do have a question. (sorry if its totally obvious answer) what is "card" in your code? do i have to create a var card? And what should it represent?

Comment: It is a list of dynamic objects. You can read into that and into list. I was just lazy and didn't feel like having an object for it or a tuple

Comment: I tried this method but was having alot of issues. i rewrote the program completely different.thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Kris - Issues? What you mean?